# Recursion Proof by Induction

Tags: induction, recursion

Given:

```
f(1) = 2
f(n) = f(n-1) + 3, for all n>1
```

It can be evaluated to:

```
f(1)=2
f(2)=f(2-1) + 3 = f(1) + 3 = 5
f(3)=f(3-1) + 3 = f(2) + 3 = 8
...
```

Or simply,

```
 f(n) = 3y-1 for all n>1
```

may be used to calculate f(n) directly.
For all n>1, f(n) follows +3 for every +n.

Next, the problem is to prove that my formula is correct through induction.
Below are my attempts.
Attempt#1

```
Prove:
3n – 1 for all n>1
    Base Case:
        n = 1, the sum is 2 and 3n-1 = 3(1)-1 = 2
    Inductive Step:
        Assume true for n=k: 3k-1
        Show true for n=k+1:
            3(k+1)-1
            3k+3-1
            3k+2
    Conclusion:
        by induction, the statement holds true for all n>1.
```

Not entirely sure if I am correct.

Attempt#2
Also tried using summation.
$\sum_{i=1}^n 2+3+3+3...+3 = 3n-1$
... 
which didn't really work well for me.

Could you clear it up for me?
Perhaps I am lost in the concept and/or overthinking this. One time I thought I got it, next thing I know I lost it when it comes to such different approach.
In my attempts, I am also lost to the different situations whether I can/should use summation for it (being that this is not much of a sequence problem, rather just 2,3,3,3,3.., I wouldn't need to?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems in Your Post

Let me first discuss the problems in your post.

- You wrote (I am $\LaTeX$'ing the text),

  > **Prove:**
  >   $3n – 1$ for all $n>1$.

  Now, as it stands the statement doesn't make sense. What is it *exactly* that you want to prove? More specifically, what is(are) your premise(s)?
- Since you don't clearly state what exactly is that you want to prove, there is no sense in proving the **Base Case** and the **Inductive Step**. But still, assuming that you have now correctly stated what you want to prove, let me point out the problem in the statement that you wrote for the **Base Case** and the **Inductive Step**.

  In the **Base Case** you wrote,

  > **Base Case:** $n = 1$, the sum is $2$ and $3n-1 = 3(1)-1 = 2$.

  Obviously the question is, what do you mean by "the sum is..."? Which sum are you referring to?

  In the **Inductive Step** you wrote,

  > **Inductive Step:** Assume true for $n=k: 3k-1$. Show true for $n=k+1$,
  >           $$3(k+1)-1\\
  >         3k+3-1\\
  >         3k-2$$

  What *exactly* do we assume to be true for $n=k$?
- Your elaboration of second attempt is more confusing. Why exactly do you want to use induction here is not clear to me. Look below for what I guess you have attempted to do.

### What (I think) Your Proofs Could be

**Attempt 1**

> **Prove:** $P(n):=f(n)=3n-1$ is true for all $n\ge1$.
>
> **Base Case:** $n = 1\implies 3n-1 = 3(1)-1 = 2=f(1)$. (So $P(1)$ is *true*.)
>
> **Inductive Step:** Assume $P(n)$ to be true for $n=k$, i.e.,$P(k)=3k-1$. Now *using this* we need to show that $P(k+1)$ is also true. Now observe that, 
>               \begin{align}f(k+1)=f(k)+3&\implies f(k+1)=(3k-1)+3 \\&\implies f(k+1)=3(k+1)-1\end{align}which shows that $P(k+1)$ is also true. (Find out where we have used the Induction Hypothesis).
>
> **Conclusion:** By induction, $P(n)$ holds true for all $n\ge 1$.

**Attempt 2**

Let $u_n=f(n+1)-f(n)$.

> **Prove:** $P(n):=f(n)=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)-1$ is true for all $n\ge 1$.
>
> **Base Case:** $n = 1\implies f(1)=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^1 u_i\right)-1=u_1-1=2$. (So $P(1)$ is *true*.)
>
> **Inductive Step:** Assume $P(n)$ to be true for $n=k$, i.e.,$P(k)=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k u_i\right)-1$. Now *using this* we need to show that $P(k+1)$ is also true. Now observe that, 
>               \begin{align}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} u_i\right)-1&=u_{k+1}+\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k u_i\right)-1 \\&=u_{k+1}+f(k)\\&=(f(k+1)-f(k))+f(k)\\&=f(k+1)\end{align}which shows that $P(k+1)$ is also true. (Find out where we have used the Induction Hypothesis).
>
> **Conclusion:** By induction, $P(n)$ holds true for all $n\ge 1$.

Though this doesn't directly yield your desired formula, you can obtain it simply by observing that $u_n=3$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof never used your assumption (the inductive hypothesis). You need to use it.

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume that $f(k) = 3k - 1$ for some $k > 0$.

We want to show that $f(k + 1) = 3(k + 1) - 1$. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
f(k + 1)
&= f(k) + 3 &\text{using the given recurrence, since } k + 1 > 1 \\
&= (3k - 1) + 3 &\text{by the inductive hypothesis} \\
&= 3k + 2 \\
&= 3(k + 1) - 1
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

In your 2. attempt you have a strange way of using $\sum$. But I would also start from a similar point and then do a direct proof.

About $\sum_{i=n_0}^{n_1} t_i$ :
I understand (define) the sum symbol like this:

1. if $n_0\le n_1$ $$\sum_{i=n_0}^{n_1}t_i = t_{n_1} + \sum_{i=n_0}^{n_1-1}t_i$$
2. else (if $n_0\gt n_1$) $$\sum_{i=n_0}^{n_1}t_i=0$$

So in your case we have to represent the recursive function as $f(n)=2+\sum_{i=2}^n3$

Now I can proof $\forall_n ( n\ge 1\to 2+\sum_{i=2}^n3=3n-1)$

1. assume $n\ge1$
2. to proof $2+\sum_{i=2}^n3=3n-1$
3. because the term inside the sum (3) does not depend on the index ($i$)  it is clear that $\sum_{i=2}^n3=3(n-1)=3n-3$
4. if you add 2 you get $3n-1$